# Compiz Grid doesn't resize to different sizes

Tags: compiz

I just started using 11.10 on my new work computer for my new job.

I used to be able to use the Grid compiz plugin so that when I hit a direction key multiple times it will cycle between 3 different sizes of the window (25% of the screen, 50%, 75%). With this fresh 11.10 install, it will only do 50%.

Does anyone have any idea what is going on?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can alter the settings for this using the Compiz Config Settings Manager.
For the Grid plugin go to the Edges tab. Then per edge you can set how it should resize.
The bindings tab will then allow you to set up the shortkeys for that.

Answer (score 2):

This is a known, confirmed bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/unity/+bug/879218